# DPI aware distorts text when screen resized with Windows API

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am writing an app in C++ with the Win32 API. I first noticed that the rendered text with `DrawTextLayout()` was very fuzzy, so I added the following line:

```cpp
SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
```

At first, this seemed to do the trick: the text looked much crisper, and more of what I would expect from a Windows app.

However, when I resized the window (by dragging the bottom corner), I noticed that the text I drew was distorted.

How could I keep the crispness of using `DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2`, but also keep the text from becoming stretched?

```
#include "targetver.h"
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers
// Windows Header Files
#include <windows.h>
// C RunTime Header Files
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <dwrite.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#define IDS_APP_TITLE           103
#define IDR_MAINFRAME           128
#define IDD_PRACTICE_DIALOG 102
#define IDD_ABOUTBOX            103
#define IDM_ABOUT               104
#define IDM_EXIT                105
#define IDI_PRACTICE            107
#define IDI_SMALL               108
#define IDC_PRACTICE            109
#define IDC_MYICON              2
#ifndef IDC_STATIC
#define IDC_STATIC              -1
#endif
#define MAX_LOADSTRING 100
// Global Variables:
HINSTANCE hInst;                                // current instance
WCHAR szTitle[MAX_LOADSTRING];                  // The title bar text
WCHAR szWindowClass[MAX_LOADSTRING];            // the main window class name
ID2D1Factory* m_pD2DFactory;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget* m_pRenderTarget;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush* m_pBlackBrush;
IDWriteFactory* writeFactory;
IDWriteTextFormat* writeTextFormat;
IDWriteTextLayout* writeTextLayout;
RECT rc;
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
ATOM MyRegisterClass(HINSTANCE hInstance)
{
    WNDCLASSEXW wcex;
    wcex.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wcex.lpfnWndProc = WndProc;
    wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
    wcex.cbWndExtra = 0;
    wcex.hInstance = hInstance;
    wcex.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_PRACTICE));
    wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(nullptr, IDC_ARROW);
    wcex.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH)(COLOR_WINDOW + 1);
    wcex.lpszMenuName = MAKEINTRESOURCEW(IDC_PRACTICE);
    wcex.lpszClassName = szWindowClass;
    wcex.hIconSm = LoadIcon(wcex.hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDI_SMALL));
    return RegisterClassExW(&wcex);
}
BOOL InitInstance(HINSTANCE hInstance, int nCmdShow)
{
    hInst = hInstance; // Store instance handle in our global variable
    HWND hWnd = CreateWindowW(szWindowClass, szTitle, WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, nullptr, nullptr, hInstance, nullptr);
    //create device independent resources
    {
        SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext(DPI_AWARENESS_CONTEXT_PER_MONITOR_AWARE_V2);
        // Create a Direct2D factory.
        D2D1CreateFactory(
            D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,
            &m_pD2DFactory
        );
        DWriteCreateFactory(
            DWRITE_FACTORY_TYPE_SHARED,
            __uuidof(IDWriteFactory),
            reinterpret_cast<IUnknown**>(&writeFactory)
        );
    }
    if (!hWnd)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
    UpdateWindow(hWnd);
    return TRUE;
}
int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
    _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
    _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
    _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
    UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
    // Initialize global strings
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDS_APP_TITLE, szTitle, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    LoadStringW(hInstance, IDC_PRACTICE, szWindowClass, MAX_LOADSTRING);
    MyRegisterClass(hInstance);
    // Perform application initialization:
    if (!InitInstance(hInstance, nCmdShow))
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    HACCEL hAccelTable = LoadAccelerators(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_PRACTICE));
    MSG msg;
    // Main message loop:
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        if (!TranslateAccelerator(msg.hwnd, hAccelTable, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessage(&msg);
        }
    }
    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (message)
    {
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        //create device dependent resources
        {
            HRESULT hr = S_OK;
            if (!m_pRenderTarget) {
                GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
                D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
                // Create a Direct2D render target 
                hr = m_pD2DFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(), D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(hWnd, size), &m_pRenderTarget);
                if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
                {
                    // Create a black brush
                    hr = m_pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::Black), &m_pBlackBrush);
                }
            }
        }
        //render text
        {
            writeFactory->CreateTextFormat(
                L"Times New Roman",
                NULL,
                DWRITE_FONT_WEIGHT_NORMAL,
                DWRITE_FONT_STYLE_NORMAL,
                DWRITE_FONT_STRETCH_NORMAL,
                14.0f,
                L"EN-US",
                &writeTextFormat
            );
            writeFactory->CreateTextLayout(
                L"String",      // The string to be laid out and formatted.
                6,  // The length of the string.
                writeTextFormat,  // The text format to apply to the string (contains font information, etc).
                200,         // The length of the layout box.
                500,        // The width of the layout box.
                &writeTextLayout  // The IDWriteTextLayout interface pointer.
            );
        }
        m_pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();
        m_pRenderTarget->SetTransform(D2D1::IdentityMatrix());
        m_pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
        m_pRenderTarget->DrawTextLayout(D2D1::Point2F(0, 0), writeTextLayout, m_pBlackBrush);
        m_pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
    }
    break;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        break;
    default:
        return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I apologize that this is a substantial amount of code; however, to be able to be completely run, I had to include this much.

Comment: I've solved a lot of DPI issues in the app I work on.  I'd love to help.  But can you post a [mcve] ? (i.e. A small .cpp program with a WinMain that demonstrates the issue.  Then I can compile it locally)

Comment: You need to refer to [Displaying properly on a high-DPI display](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct2d/how-to--size-a-window-properly-for-high-dpi-displays) to ensure that your application runs properly on a high-DPI display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although setting dpi-awareness is a critical step to avoid bluriness on high-res monitors (when dpi is not 100%), your issue with the text getting stretched on a window resize is a separate issue.

This is simply a DirectX (DirectWrite) surface issue.  I only have limited experience with DirectWrite, but the fix for this is very obvious.  Like D3D, the DirectWrite surface stretches across the size of the window, but it's not directly aware of the window size change until you tell it.

Potentially two very easy fixes:

In your `WndProc` function, pass the new size to the `m_pRenderTarget` thing when the size changes.  Catch `WM_SIZE`:

```
case WM_SIZE:
{
    if (m_pRenderTarget)
    {
        GetClientRect(hWnd, &rc);
        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right - rc.left, rc.bottom - rc.top);
        m_pRenderTarget->Resize(size);
    }
    break;
}
```

Alternatively, since your `WM_PAINT` code would re-create the thing anyway if it's null:

```
case WM_SIZE:
{
    if (m_pRenderTarget)
    {
        m_pRenderTarget->Release();
        m_pRenderTarget = nullptr;
    }
    break;
}
```

One other minor fix.  Invoke `SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext` **before** you call CreateWindow. Very early in WinMain before you start doing anything else. Or use the [application manifest file to set it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process).